# PHP: move values of array under others keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [amount_positive] => 10.00
            [negative_sum] => -5,7
            [negative] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -3.00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -2.00
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -0.70
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [amount_positive] => 6.00
            [negative_sum] => -7
            [negative] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -7
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

You can note that key 0 has +10.00 of positive and -5.7 of negative (they are money transactions).

Key 1 has +13 and -7.

Basically, I need to iterate into array and move 4.30 under key 0, taken from THE NEGATIVE of key 1.

This is must be the final array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [amount_positive] => 10.00
            [negative_sum] => -10.00
            [negative] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -3.00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -2.00
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -0.70
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [amount] => -4.30
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [amount_positive] => 6.00
            [negative_sum] => -2.70
            [negative] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (

                            [amount] => -2.70
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: why in the second array index did the negative move from -7 to -2.7

Comment: because I moved 4.30 on first index. If I am not wrong, 7-4.30 = 2.70 :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need code that performs the transformation on this particular array (where you know the array indexes), the following will do what you want:

```
$expense = -4.30;

$your_array[0]['negative'][] = ['amount' => $expense];
$your_array[0]['negative_sum'] +=  $expense;


$your_array[1]['negative'][0]['amount'] -= $expense;
$your_array[1]['negative_sum'] -=  $expense;
```

If you want a more "general" approach for arbitrary indexes and arbitrary `amount` entries, you will need to rephrase your question in broader terms.